# Git hooks: How to force a file change to be included?

Tags: git, github, githooks

I want to force a `*.md` change if anything is committed to a specific branch.
A `CHANGELOG.md` where a commit must be translated to non-tech support staff.

Pseudo code

```
if branch == master && changes(CHANGELOG.md).isEmpty
  return false
else 
  return true
```

Comment: "example code" in what language? what isn't working? what have you tried?

Comment: Looks like pseudo code to me.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch --show-current` will get you the branch.
`git diff --cached --name-only` will get you the names of the files in the commit.

*HOWEVER*, and this is what brought me here, is it looks like at least the latter does not work for `git commit --amend`.  So it is likely not a complete solution, but might help you get started in searching for a better one.